# color of string in lstdefinelanguage

Tags: color, listings

I have a latex document like this, where I define my own lstlsting language:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\definecolor{keywords1}{RGB}{193,89,45}
\definecolor{keywords2}{RGB}{55,80,146}
\definecolor{string}{RGB}{72,94,70}
 
\lstdefinelanguage{Python}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywords=[1]{class, import},
    keywordstyle=[1]\color{keywords1},
    keywords=[2]{print},
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{keywords2},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{string}\ttfamily,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=none,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
import pandas as pd
import qnorm

df = pd.DataFrame({'C1': {'A': 5, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4},
                   'C2': {'A': 4, 'B': 1, 'C': 4, 'D': 2},
                   'C3': {'A': 3, 'B': 4, 'C': 6, 'D': 8}})

print(qnorm.quantile_normalize(df, axis=1))

         C1        C2        C3
A  5.666667  5.166667  2.000000
B  2.000000  2.000000  3.000000
C  3.000000  5.166667  4.666667
D  4.666667  3.000000  5.666667
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

this produces:
[image]

How do I make sure the text in between the apostrophe's (') is colored by my defined string color? I have tried adding a stringstyle, but it seems like the apostrophe isn't recognized as string. Neither are other symbols, e.g. "

What am I doing wrong...?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You need to add the `string` character to your `Python` language definition, so add `string=[b]{'}`.

Comment: @Werner indeed, that works!! If you put it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande: Done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specific the string character used in your newly-defined language. Do this by adding

```
string = [b]{'}
```

to your list of options. From the [`listings`](//ctan.org/pkg/listings) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/listings) (section **4.7 Language definitions**):

> **Strings**
>
> `string=[⟨b|d|m|bd|s⟩]{⟨delimiter (character)⟩}` 
> `morestring=[⟨b|d|m|bd|s⟩]{⟨delimiter⟩}` 
> `deletestring=[⟨b|d|m|bd|s⟩]{⟨delimiter⟩}`
>
> define, add to or delete the delimiter from the list of string delimiters. Starting and ending delimiters are the same, i.e. in the source code the delimiters
> must match each other.
>
> The optional argument is the type and controls the how the delimiter itself
> is represented in a string or character literal: it is escaped by a `b`ackslash,
> `d`oubled (or both is allowed via `bd`). Alternately, the type can refer to an
> unusual form of delimiter: string delimiters (akin to the `s` comment type) or
> `m`atlab-style delimiters. The latter is a special type for Ada and Matlab and
> possibly other languages where the string delimiters are also used for other
> purposes. It is equivalent to `d`, except that a string does not start after a
> letter, a right parenthesis, a right bracket, or some other characters.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\definecolor{keywords1}{RGB}{193,89,45}
\definecolor{keywords2}{RGB}{55,80,146}
\definecolor{string}{RGB}{72,94,70}
 
\lstdefinelanguage{Python}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywords=[1]{class, import},
    keywordstyle=[1]\color{keywords1},
    keywords=[2]{print},
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{keywords2},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    string=[b]{'},
    stringstyle=\color{string}\ttfamily,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=none,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=true,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
import pandas as pd
import qnorm

df = pd.DataFrame({'C1': {'A': 5, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4},
                   'C2': {'A': 4, 'B': 1, 'C': 4, 'D': 2},
                   'C3': {'A': 3, 'B': 4, 'C': 6, 'D': 8}})

print(qnorm.quantile_normalize(df, axis=1))

         C1        C2        C3
A  5.666667  5.166667  2.000000
B  2.000000  2.000000  3.000000
C  3.000000  5.166667  4.666667
D  4.666667  3.000000  5.666667
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```